# how can i make a low poly render on blender internal viewport render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

*long story short, how can i make this kind of render in the viewport render* **(blender internal)**
[image]

p.s   : i am open to any suggestion, so don't be shy and tell me about it :D
p.s.s : i am not a native speaker so here is a forefront apologies if there is any misconception, or hard to understand part of this question.

Thank you :]

Comment: Is there a reason why you won't make it in cycles?

Comment: By kind of render, do you mean the lighting effect (which to me looks like some fading between cartoony colors), or do you mean how would you model such a scene, or something else? @LukeD While cycles is great, it seems that this lighting style matches the BI pretty well, might as well use it (unless there is something that you need Cycles for that is).

Comment: @Gliderman I know it could be done in BI but I don't know anything useful about it. On the other hand (for me) it's pretty easy in cycles.

Comment: @LukeD : for the computer i have used right now cycles is a monstrously hungry on memory and i don't have the money and time to render a scene in it..

Comment: @Gliderman : yes it is! i am looking for a way to render (as in lighting effect, simply how can i make that kind of look in my scene!)that kind of scene using viewport render or blender internal (viewport render is a + for me since i can edit it directly XD)
p.s : just ask me if my question is not clear enough (english is not my first language after all) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Final]

As I mentioned before. Blender Render isn't my thing, but I think result is pretty close.

### Materials:

I've used mostly default material. Just set *Diffuse* color and lower *Specularity > Intensinity* to *0.2*.

[image: Material]

### Light:

Again, as simple as it can be.

*Lamp* set to *Sun* with *Sky* turned on. 
*Shadow* > *Ray Shadow* with *Sampling* > *5* and *Soft Size* > *5*.

[image: Light]

**Note.** Postion Light directly from top to bottom to have shadows right beneath objects.

### World:

Under *World* tab set *Horizontal* an *Zenith Color* to some candy like colors.
Switch on *Environment Lighthing* and set it to *Sky Color*.

[image: World]

### Blend file:

And here to play with.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer!, but the material is slightly off (i want a slightly fading cartoonish color just like the example) i really appreciate the answer ! XD

Comment: In Materials under Specular change CockTorr to Toon. Don't forget that in example image texture was used.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i've actually fiddle through the blend file and after comparing it through several times i realized i only need to add ambient occlusion to the render files! (lol), Thank you!

Comment: I've fristly tried AO but it gives me strange results. As I said. Really simple task for me in Cycles first try in Blender Render ;)